# How does STAB work with Terastalized Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

So let’s say we had a dual type fire ghost, any fire/ghost move will have that 1.5X STAB boost. But when it’s terastallized, let’s say fire, fire moves will have 2X boost, but does ghost moves stay 1.5X or return to 1X?

Answer (score 4):

When you Terastalize, the Pokémon will receive a 2x STAB bonus if it is of the same type while also keeping the standard STAB bonus of the other type

> While Terastallized, Pokémon receive STAB on moves matching their Tera Type, **in addition to moves matching their original types**. If the Pokémon's Tera Type is the same as one of its original types, moves of that type receive an ×2 power boost instead of the usual ×1.5.

[Source](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Terastal_phenomenon)